# Intellij not recognising drawable folders for android

Tags: android, intellij-idea, splash-screen

I'm trying to set up a splash screen for PhoneGap in Intellij Community edition 11.12.

The problem is that Intellij gives me the error 'cannot resolve symbol splash' - for some reason it's not picking up R.drawable.splash - I've rebuilt the project and deleted the generated files, but that doesn't help.

I have the following folder structure (looks correct from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)

```
-res
--drawable
----splash.png
--drawable-hdpi
----splash.png
--drawable-mdpi
----splash.png
--drawable-ldpi
----splash.png
--drawable-xhdpi
----splash.png
```

And I'm trying to set the splash screen with:

```
package com.illbeintouch.mobile;

import android.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.DroidGap;

public class MyActivity extends DroidGap
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
        super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 5000);
    }
}
```

I don't know if it makes a difference, but I'm using 1.7 Java SDK, and android 2.3.3 as the target platform.

If you can help out I'd be super grateful - I've spent all morning trying to sort this thing out!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to find splash in default R class:

```
import android.R;
```

Remove this import and import appropriate autogenerated R.